Could NOT find Vitis (missing: Vitis_FLOATING_POINT_LIBRARY)
I am using gemm_hls opensource project on Xilinx U250 , and when I run the cmake command，
cmake ../ -DMM_DATA_TYPE=float -DMM_PARALLELISM_N=32 -DMM_PARALLELISM_M=8 -DMM_MEMORY_TILE_SIZE_N=512 -DMM_MEMORY_TILE_SIZE_M=512
the following error is reported. I am not sure if it is an environment variable problem, or the path is not specified, or Vitis is not installed completely? Can anyone help me?enter image description here
I confirmed that the environment variables should be effective, and also confirmed that the Vitis installation is complete through vitis_tutorial.
